# Azure Service Bus queues close after 24 hours automatically

Tags: azure, servicebus

### Problem

We are developing a Azure Service Bus based Cloud Service, but after 24 hours the queue clients seem to get closed automatically. 
Can someone confirm this behavior or give advise how to fix it?
At the moment we close the clients after 24 hours manually and recreate them to avoid this effect, but this can't be the only solution.

Comment: What is the symptom by which you tell that the clients are "closed"?

Comment: An System.OperationCanceledException is thrown with the message "The operation cannot be performed because the entity has been closed or aborted."

Comment: Is that happening inside the datacenter or from somewhere at your development site?

Comment: I don't understand your question. The cloud service tries to receive messages in a while-loop, but after 24-48 hours the exception above occurs. What we did is to reset the connection programmatically after 24 hours to prevent the clients from being closed.

Comment: The exception means is that your client has faulted, i.e. the session got dropped. Sessions dropping is something your app should generally anticipate. Are you using AMQP? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-amqp-dotnet

Comment: We are not using AMQP

Comment: Is service bus messaging via AMQP protocol aware of session dropping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sessions dropping intermittently is a normal occurrence. The AMQP protocol and stack in the client is newer and generally more resilient against this. The only reason not to use AMQP is if you are using transactions. Also, unless you have a good reason to run your own receive loop, use OnMessage.

You are getting ‘OperationCanceledException’ when the link fails for any reason and any in-flight requests will fail with this exception. However, this is transient, so you should be able to reuse the same QueueClient to issue receives and those should (eventually) work as the client recovers. OnMessage will hide all of that from you.

Comment: Great, thank you - I will test the AMQP protocol with OnMessage for our application.

Comment: It works now - I will check back after 24-48 hours if it is still running